# How to verify if a clean windows 7 install was done or an upgrade over vista was what the tech did?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, upgrade, comparison

I'd like to know if the install was truly done as a clean Windows 7 or If the windows 7 was installed over the vista as an upgrade - 32 bit and ultimate verstion?

I noticed hp game stuff (wild tanget or something ) during an virus scan and it was not suppose to be in a clean install...so now I'm wondering how to verify what kind of install Really happened/

Any help?  I'd appreaciate knowing how to know the difference, if I was led to believe something that was not true...I paid for a clean install.  Did I get that or not is my concern>

Thank you so much
Melody

Comment: As long as you don't suspect that your pc is still infected, I wouldn't worry too much. To be safe: use your computer as a restricted user and prevent a lot nasty things from happening

Answer (score 3):

Check for a **C:\Windows.old** folder.

If he did an upgrade from Vista, the Vista files are left intact to restore files and settings.

It also helps if you check the **C:\Program Files** or **C:\Users** for folders that are older than the newest installation date.

If it really was a clean install, I'd imagine that he formatted the drive and nothing from the previous installation should be left behind.

Answer (score 0):

The "HP game stuff" (Wild Tangent) comes with HP OEM installs. Arguably an OEM install is not a clean install, but the presence of that sort of rubbish doesn't mean that the drive wasn't formatted just yesterday.

Comment: yea, and the Wild Tangent software shows up as spyware/malware in many AV software programs.  It's basically AD-ware, though.